# Data successfully retrieved from database but can't pass through the adapter class

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, observer-pattern

Well... i want to show data retrieved from firebase database in RecycleView and do further stuffs like editing,updating etc. So, i'm using observable pattern to retrieve data(which successfully did) and trying to pass data to the constructor and the adapter class. The data did show up in the constructor class but didn't load in adapter class and also in the RecycleView.

Fragment class or main class

```
public class overviewFragment extends Fragment {

View view;
public static RecyclerView overRecycleView;
public overviewFragment() {}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.overview_fragment, container, false);
    overRecycleView = view.findViewById(R.id.overViewRecycle);
    overviewRecyclerAdapter adapter = new overviewRecyclerAdapter(getContext(), observerData.overViewlist);
    overRecycleView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
   // adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    overRecycleView.setAdapter(adapter);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    observableData ob =new observableData();
    observerData observerData = new observerData(ob)
    ob.setMeasurement();
    ob.setMeasurement();  }}
```

Observable class to retrieve firebase data and notify observer

```
public class observableData extends Observable {
private String data;

public observableData() { }

public void setMeasurement(){
    final DatabaseReference n = ScrollingActivityforTutor.db();

    n.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String a = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
            Log.d("name from database ", a);

            data =a;

            measurementChanged();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}

public void measurementChanged(){
    setChanged();
    notifyObservers();
}

public String getData() {
    return data;
}
}
```

Observer class from where constructor class will be called

```
public class observerData implements  Observer {
Observable observable;
public String data;
public static List<itemOverview> overViewlist = new ArrayList<>();;

public observerData(Observable observable) {
    this.observable = observable;
    observable.addObserver(this);
}

@Override
public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
    observableData od = (observableData) o;
    this.data = od.getData();
    passData();
}

public void passData(){
    overViewlist.add(new itemOverview(data));
    Log.d("data in observer ", data);
}
}
```

Constructor class

```
public class itemOverview {

private String text;

public itemOverview(String text) {
    Log.d("IN CONSTRUCTOR ", text);  // It is perfectly showing the data
    this.text = text;
}

public String getText() {
    return text;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}}
```

Adapter class

```
 public class overviewRecyclerAdapter extends 
 RecyclerView.Adapter<overviewRecyclerAdapter.overviewViewHolder> {
 Context mcontext;
 List<itemOverview> mdata;

 public overviewRecyclerAdapter(Context mcontext, List<itemOverview> mdata) 
{
    this.mcontext = mcontext;
    this.mdata = mdata;  }

public static class overviewViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    private TextView t;

    public overviewViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        t = itemView.findViewById(R.id.overViewtextView); }}

@NonNull
@Override
public  overviewRecyclerAdapter.overviewViewHolder 
onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v;
    v = LayoutInflater.from(mcontext).inflate(R.layout.item_overview, 
    parent, false);
    overviewViewHolder overview = new overviewViewHolder(v);
    return overview;  }

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull 
overviewRecyclerAdapter.overviewViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Log.d("IN ADAPTER ", mdata.get(position).getText());  // HERE, IT IS 
    NOT WORKING

    holder.t.setText(mdata.get(position).getText());

}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mdata.size() ;
}}
```

But when i use measurementChanged() (in the observable class) outside the onDatachange method and put data (variable) with some string value, everything worked and the given data showed up in the recycleView.

dont understand where the problem is and where to debug.

However, SORRY for such big miles of codes :)
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see that you are trying to add elements to a RecyclerView programmatically. But the RecyclerView is not updated when you update the array containing the necessary data. As you have made the RecyclerView static, you can easily notify the changes to the adapter using the following code:

```
public void passData(){
    overViewlist.add(new itemOverview(data));
    Log.d("data in observer ", data);

    overviewRecyclerAdapter adapter = (overviewRecyclerAdapter) overviewFragment.overRecycleView.getAdapter();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();        
}
```

There are much better ways of doing this. `adapter.notifyItemInserted(overViewlist.size()-1);` is probably a better solution in your case (in terms of performance).

P.S. You should follow the naming conventions in java to make your code more readable.